# Not entering JavaScript 'for' loop (for adding to a table)

Tags: javascript

Right now I have the following code, which is an excerpt from my entire code.

```
console.log(characters);
var table= "<table><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'>Name</td>";
table+= "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: left;'>Description</td>";
table+="<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: left;'>Picture</td></tr>";

table+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;                   '>---------------</td>";
table+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>";
table+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>";

for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
                console.log('in loop');
                char_name = characters[i].data.results[0].name;
                console.log(char_name);
                char_description = characters[i].data.results[0].description;
                image_url = characters[i].data.results[0].thumbnail.path+'/standard_medium.jpg';


                table+="<tr><td style='width: 100px; text-align: left;'>" + char_name + "</td>";
                table+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: left;'>" + char_description + "</td>";
                table+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: left;'>"+'<img src=' + image_url  
                            +' alt="hero icon"'+' style=float:left'+'>'+'</img></td></tr>';
            };

   table+= '</table>';
   console.log(table);
   $('#result').append(table);
```

characters is an array of objects that have data that I want to place into an html file. The for loop is never entered. Neither console.log() in the for loop actually appears in my console, while when console.log(table) is called, the table html is just the html that was written outside of the loop. What is incorrect here?

Comment: `characters` is an array..? if yes, what is the value of `characters.length` ?`console.log('in loop');` never fires?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(characters);`?

Comment: This would be a better question if the code were complete enough that others could run it.  To improve it, edit the code to define characters and set it explicitly and appropriately (possibly simplifying the extraction code in the loop), and remove the jQuery at the end. Then this could be run by others very easily.

Comment: Sorry, Paul. The code is quite long and involves others files to run correctly. It also includes calls to an API, which then populates the characters array.

Comment: @sj20 Well, the async filling of characters explains most of it, along with a little creative cut/paste to ask the question.  I couldn't see the bug in your code above. That's one reason stack overflow wants posts to be minimal-complete-verifiable-examples.

Answer (score 0):

My guess will be to check the elements in your `characters` array. Try both `console.log(characters.length);` and `console.log(characters[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You not give your characters length. if it's empty, for loop will never fire

Below I demonstrate in the Chrome debugger what happens if `characters` is set to `[1,2,3,4]` and a breakpoint set in the loop.  As you can see, the loop would then be entered.  You can access the debugger with Control+Shift+J.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

characters.length is 0.

Otherwise your code will enter the loop or crash.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your quick responses! Yes, characters.length was 0, even though console.log(characters) gave me a list fully populated. I realized that characters is asynchronously populated, which leads me to a whole other problem to solve.